# What are the Beej, Vedic and Tantric mantras of all the navagrahas?

Tags: mantras, rituals, astrology, tantra, navagraha

I have heard astrologers at times, specifically advising to use  the *Beej Mantras* of a particular *graha* as remedy for the respective planetary afflictions.

At other times, they specifically advice to use the *Vedic  Mantras* for a *graha* and not use the *Beej Mantra*.

Sometimes, only advice to specifically use the *Tantric Mantras*.

So, My question:

- Although it is kind of obvious from their names, but, what's exactly the difference (if any) between these **three classes** of *Mantras* - *Beej*, *Vedic* & *Tantric*? In terms of usages in rituals or pronounciation, methods used, etc., ?
- Can I get the list of all the three types of *Mantras* - *Beej*, *Vedic* & *Tantric* for all the *nava-grahas*?
- What's the basis for using different **classes** of  *Mantras* as per different problem remedies? Which texts might be suggesting these kind of differential remedies?

Comment: FYI, while you may get textual answers here, if you plan to actually chant them, you have to get initiated from a guru, preferably one who has attained siddhi, or bhakti. Reason is many mantras do not work without devotion, and to make up for it, you need a 'recommendation' letter to the devata, and the guru provides that.

Comment: @mar, I know about the initiation - *deeksha* stuff, I'm asking this just out of curious inquisition, definitely not for self practice.

Comment: You can get one set from [here](https://www.astrojyoti.com/mantras2.htm)@Vivikta

Comment: See [this](https://archive.org/details/RudrayamalaTantram_201712/page/n255/mode/2up) (the table)

Comment: @Proxy, this is helpful. Thanks.